# how to access assets files in phonegap native android plugin from app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have created a phonegap application using cordova CLI and created my own cordova plugin for android say `myPGplugin`. I have a requirement that i want to place some images in `assets/www/img/` folder so that it will be used for both android and iOS platforms related plugins, lets say `image1.jpg` placed in `img` folder, and i want to access this `image1.jpg` into my native android phonegap plugin.
How can i access this `image1.jpg` into my native plugin codes using phonegap. 
can some one please help  in this.

thanks in advance for helping me in finding out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

after doing some research and hands on , i got the answer to my question

```
AssetManager assetManager = mCordova.getActivity().getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    istr = assetManager.open(assetPath);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
```

this will help you to access the image files from asset folder in cordova/phone gap app